# bottom layout guide changing

Tags: ios, autolayout

When I start up my app, the bottom layout guide has these dimensions;

<_UILayoutGuide: 0xd687730; frame = (0 519; 0 49); hidden = YES; layer = >

Which is correct, because my Tab bar has a custom background which isn't transparent. The content of the view controller is a table view.

However, when i go to next tab and go back, the bottom layout has changed:

<_UILayoutGuide: 0xd687730; frame = (0 568; 0 0); hidden = YES; layer = >

What is changing this and why? Any clues please.